# Long term solution to running 3D applications in a virtual machine or container

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, container

I have a complex script written a few years ago and, although it currently works, almost every time I upgrade my machine something gets broken, and maintaining it really hinders my work. It acts as a glue between Google Earth and utilities like xdotool, wmctrl, and devilspie2. Now that Wayland is being implemented in the major compositors, the future looks bleak for such utilities.

Running this script from a container or virtual machine will provide me with the following benefits:

1. Upgrading or modifying my desktop without breaking the script.
2. The ability to take snapshots, which would reduce much of the complexity in trying to auto-save my work, fixing some current bugs.

The problem is that I have not found any optimal solution to running 3D applications with hardware acceleration from a container or virtual machine on a Linux host. The guest can be any Linux system, but could also be Windows with the script rewritten in AutoHotkey.

I have seen some [hackish and dangerous solutions](http://gernotklingler.com/blog/howto-get-hardware-accelerated-opengl-support-docker/) to running 3D applications from a container, and which depend on X11 in the host.

There is `virtio-gpu` too, supported by QEMU 2.5 + virglrenderer, with Linux 4.4 and Mesa 11.1+ in the guest. There are packages for [virglrenderer on Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=813658), but even the packagers were unable to get 3D acceleration to work in the guest so far!

Comment: Xen supports allocating individual PCI devices to different virtualization domains. You could move the PCI device from dom0 (the domain to which it is allocated by default, indeed the domain to which all PCI devices are allocated by default) to the domU where you want to use 3D features. You have to be careful because then dom0 will end up without a video device to use as a console so ideally dom0 would have a serial console or something.

Comment: @Celada That means I would have 3D acceleration available for this environment only, and not in my desktop anymore?

Comment: Correct. Indeed you wouldn't *have* any other desktop anymore.

Comment: @Celada Thank you, but that is out of the question!

Comment: A dedicated server, hosted externally (digital ocean, AWS, azure) likely will be your best option.